# Allow reqests by self but not by a user

Tags: apache-http-server, http, web

I have a few files on my apache2 web server (like passwords and technical files) that should be not accessable by users but by the web server pages. Also I'd like to make it possible to whitelist other websites.

The question is: how do I do that?

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: @harrymc Linux, of course